# Why iOS mobile doesn't open woocommerce links?

Tags: ios, css, wordpress

I am building a woocommerce website and dealing with a very strange problem on iOS mobile, when I click on a link (especially image of a product, its title, the header logo) on iOS mobile nothing happens.

On the browser and on android, everything works fine, I can click the image, the description, the header logo and they will bring me to their destination.

On iOS version 17 mobile for some reason those links doesn't work. After trying to click on them multiple times I can't even highlight the image or the text.

I use the latest woocommerce version and this happens almost on any iOS device. Sometimes in older iOS versions it seams that after clicking on a link (image, description, header logo) twice of three-four times it works and finally gets you to the destination.

Can anyone please help me?

The website is: [www.sarracollections.com](http://www.sarracollections.com)

Thanks in advance